Finding even numbers with common variables using multithreading
public partial class Program
{
    static int numberOfOddNumbers = 0;
    static int numberOfEvenNumbers = 0;
    const int N = 10000000;
    static int[] numbers = new int[N];
    static int low = 0; static int up = N - 1;

    static void CalculateLow()
    {
        while (low < up)
        {
            if (numbers[low] % 2 == 0)
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfEvenNumbers);
            else
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfOddNumbers);
            low++;
        }
    }

    static void CalculateUp()
    {
        while (up > low)
        {
            if (numbers[up] % 2 == 0)
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfEvenNumbers);
            else
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfOddNumbers);
            up--;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = i;
        }
        Thread t1 = new Thread(CalculateLow); 
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(CalculateUp);
        t2.IsBackground = true; 
        t2.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(t1.IsAlive);
        t1.Join();
        Console.WriteLine(t1.IsAlive);
        t2.Join();
        Console.WriteLine($"Odd numbers {numberOfOddNumbers}, " +
            $"even numbers: { numberOfEvenNumbers}");
     }
}

So my problem is that I am trying to find even and odd numbers in the array, therefore I am aware of the outcome, it should always be the variable N.
However in some cases its possible that the addition of the odd and even numbers are N+1!
Since I am having shared variables (up,low) in the while cycle's conditions I am curious if it's the root of the problem or not? Also I am not sure if it's safe to increase or decrease the common variables without lock or interlocked.

The two threads can be squabbling over up and low, both of which are changing. Inherent race condition, and also forces a lot of CPU cache invalidations. Why not just partition the data in half, and let each thread deal with their individual contiguous chunk? So take N, one thread deals with i=0;i<N/2;i++, the other deals with j=N/2;j<N;j++. Also, if your real scenario is even remotely similar: SIMD

Additional note: it is significantly cheaper to increment a local counter with just ++ and then call Interlocked.Add once (per counter) than it is to call Interlocked.Increment per element. And this gets even more important as you add more threads.

The answers suggesting using the Interlocked class are appropriate for getting this logic to work. But since you already have an array of all your values, you may get better performance using a Parallel.ForEach loop and giving it more than a 2 max degree of parallelism. Much less code to maintain that way as well, or leave the options default and let MS handle the thread management.

So the better apprpoach is using interlocked.increment(ref low) over low--?


Since I am having shared variables (up, low) in the while cycle's conditions I am curious if it's the root of the problem or not?

Most likely it is.

Also I am not sure if it's safe to increase or decrease the common variables without lock or interlocked.

Generally it's not. Multithreading is not trivial, and lock-free multithreading is 10 times harder. To write correct lock-free multithreaded programs you must study the C# memory model, understand how the C# compiler or the .NET Jitter or the CPU processor can reorder the instructions of your program in a way that is only visible when multiple threads are involved, learn about memory barriers, understand the purpose and learn the use of the volatile keyword etc. If you have ample time in your hands and you are brave, go and learn these things. But if you want to be successful in writing correct C# programs in the short term, you'd better stick with the lock-based synchronization, to make sure that only one thread at a time interacts with your shared state.

Thanks for the reply. I would like to know that in this exact solution which is the better solution, using up++ or Interlocked.increment(up)?

@Bnc147 I think neither. Generally you can't write correct multithreaded code by doing just minor adjustments on existing single-threaded code. Usually you have to rethink the whole approach, devising alternative strategies that are compatible with multithreading environments. Many strategies just don't work in these environments. You learn this from experience.

Thanks for your answer. This was a task we have to sold for university exercise and i would liked to know that regarding the up and low variables which is the better solution using interlocked or not. Unfortunately i understand this is bad approach but we have to make out the best from this solution, so i have to stick with this approach. I guess using interlocked is the better approach if im not mistaken.

@Bnc147 my philosophy is that if two approaches produce incorrect behavior or incorrect results, no one is better than the other. It's like two surgical procedures that both result in the death of the patient, and asking which is best, the faster or the slower procedure. Correctness is the primary goal, and if this goal is not achieved, any other secondary goal is irrelevant.

So you seem to be aware of Interlocked.Increment, since you've used it multiple times. Instead of manually incrementing and decrementing low and up, use the same interlocked operations on them.
It's actually even worse, because there is no guarantee that the compiler will actually insert a variable read to see updates other threads do to those variables. After all, from the point of view of CalculateLow, up never changes, so it can be read once and stored as a register.
That's where Interlocked.Read comes in, to force an (atomic) variable read.
So with all of that together, your code can be corrected to:
static void CalculateLow()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int lowCopy = Interlocked.Read(ref low), 
            upCopy = Interlocked.Read(ref up);

        if (lowCopy < upCopy) break;
        
        if (numbers[lowCopy] % 2 == 0)
            Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfEvenNumbers);
        else
            Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfOddNumbers);

        Interlocked.Increment(ref low);
    }
}


Note that I'm not saying that this is good code. It's simply correct.

Even with the interlocked read, I don't think this rules out a scenario where both threads process the final (somewhere near the middle) element. Honestly, I think it is a bad idea to try and even posit all the scenarios here, because of how easy it would be to be wrong; the "just just it in half" approach (comments on the question) would be much simpler to achieve guaranteed correctness. Achieving correctness when all the boundary conditions change each iteration is also a good way to make it much sloooower than a simple "cut it in half" approach

It's true, this doesn't cover the last element race condition. I guess you could use some compare-exchange loops to guarantee the state, but at that point you pretty much created a home-brew critical section (user-land mutex for the Linux people).

Thanks for your answers.It was a specific exercise in university and i wanted to know the precise solution."So you seem to be aware of Interlocked.increment since you've used it multiple times. Instead of manually incrementing and decrementing low and up, use the same interlocked operations on them.
Thanks"It's actually even worse, because there is no guarantee that the compiler will actually insert a variable read to see updates other threads do to those variables".Did you mean that using interlocked on "low" and "up" is actually worse than manually increasing?

Executing your code a few times will produce occasionally wrong result as you mentioned like below:
Odd numbers 5000001, even numbers: 5000000

The reason why it could be not as you expected because you code may expecting CPU clock are evenly distributed.
If you also print the value of up and low you will see result like this:
Odd numbers 5000000, even numbers: 5000001, up: 5086737, low: 5086739
Odd numbers 5000000, even numbers: 5000000, up: 4902256, low: 4902257
Odd numbers 5000000, even numbers: 5000001, up: 5049097, low: 5049099

If all you need is attempt to make use of CPU cores for a lengthly task, you can make use of parallelism:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
    Parallel.ForEach(numbers , x => {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfEvenNumbers);
        } 
        else {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfOddNumbers);
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"Odd numbers {numberOfOddNumbers}, even numbers: { numberOfEvenNumbers}");
}


I bet that this code is slower than doing the calculation sequentially on a single thread. The cost of Interlocked.Increment should dwarf the benefits of parallelization.

@TheodorZoulias plus parallelization should usually be "chunky"; having the callback per array element will add an absurd amount of overhead
